# Who would have won the 2020 election if "did not vote" was a candidate

Tags: united-states, elections

This infographic was posted in 2016:
[image]
The image takes the assumption that all eligible voters (registered or not) in the US who did not vote instead voted for a hypothetical "did not vote" candidate. Similar claims are made every election, with similar results- "did not vote wins by a landslide"

However, 2020 had a much higher turnout. Would the results have still been a "did not vote" victory?

Comment: This was previously Closed, and previous comments and OP suggested this be migrated to [Politics.SE].  Unfortunately that failed because presently OP is suspended there.

Comment: @feetwet I did not know suspensions blocked migration. Interesting.

Comment: Why should you be able to keep posting questions somewhere you're suspended by getting a moderator to move them from somewhere you're not suspended?

Comment: This question does not belong here but Politics.SE. As we can't migrate it to the proper stack due to OP being suspended there, we should delete it in an extraordinary deletion.

Comment: @Trish I disagree. Off-topic does not merit extraordinary deletion, especially when there are accepted and upvoted answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at the total eligible voters numbers from [here](https://worldpopulationreview.com/state-rankings/voter-turnout-by-state) and the vote distribution [here](https://cookpolitical.com/2020-national-popular-vote-tracker). Unless I screwed up my combining the two data sets, there were no states in 2020 where "Didn't vote" was the plurality. Even if you combine "Did not vote" with the third party votes, that's not enough for a plurality.

Answer (score 2):

We don't know, because this is only vaguely an option [in Nevada](https://www.leg.state.nv.us/nrs/nrs-293.html#NRS293Sec269). In Nevada, "[none of the these candidates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/None_of_These_Candidates)" is ignored in determining who wins:

> Only votes cast for the named candidates shall be counted in
> determining nomination or election to any statewide office or
> presidential nominations or the selection of presidential electors,
> but for each office the number of ballots on which the additional line
> was chosen shall be listed following the names of the candidates and
> the number of their votes in every posting, abstract and proclamation
> of the results of the election.

However, this does require that you vote. Some jurisdictions have provisions (for special levies) requiring a certain level of voter turnout to validate the levy, but no jurisdiction requires a minimum threshold of votes for elective office to deem that the winner actually wins.

States would have to pass laws allowing this to happen, for example directing that no electors shall be chosen if ___ (a majority of citizens over age 18 do not cast a presidential ballot?). In that case, the House of Representatives would decide who wins. Or, the Supreme Court would, because everybody and their horse would sue over the constitutionality of such a law.

Answer (score -5):

So, there are several options that would unfold based on the meaning of "Did Not Vote":

1. "Did Not Vote" represents the total number of eligible voters who did not fill out a ballot.   This is what happened in real life, and while you really ought to vote in any election, no one is forcing you to and you shouldn't be shamed if you choose not to.  It's your right to not give your support to the lesser of two evils.  The election proceeds as normal and Trump wins.
2. There is a human being with the unlikely name of "Did not Vote" (He presumably is the right fielder on the same baseball team as Who, What, and I Don't Know).  If he was elected on a ballot either by being on the list of candidates, or by write in candidate, than Mr. Vote wins in a landslide.
3. All or most states in gray enact a voter law that says if a candidate does not win a majority of all eligible voters (instead of majority of all ballots cast) than 41 of the 50 states affirm a "Null" candidate was selected.   Because you cannot have no president, this means that with 51 electoral votes for Hilary and 16 electoral votes for Trump, no eligible candidate recieves 270 required to be president.   The House is tasked with picking the President and the Senate the VP.  In the House this is not a simple which party has control as the there is one vote in the house for every state delegation (I.E.  California's 53 representatives must decide among themselves how to allocate their 1 vote for POTUS while Montana's 1 representative has to argue with himself).  This means that the majority party in the House might not be an indication of who is President (In 2016 I believe the Republicans had a majority by State Deligation while in 2020 the Republicans have a Majority by State Deligation despite Democrats having an overall individual majority.  It should be pointed out that in 2016 votes by Representative district, only five states with 2 or more Represenatives had a single party lock on the entire state.).  Over in the Senate, VP is picked by the same voting process, with each state getting two votes.  As Republicans had majority in both cases at this time, the race goes to Trump.

Comment: Why in case 1 isn't it "Biden wins"?